# Does the algebra of bounded variation functions have a "noncommutative geometric" meaning and generalization? 

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, noncommutative-geometry

According to Gelfand-Naimark theory, $C^*$-algebras of continuous functions $\mathcal{C}^0(X,\mathbb{C})$ on a compact Hausdorff topological space completely capture its topology. Furthermore, every commutative $C^*$-algebra arises in this way.
In noncommutative geometry (NCG), noncommutative $C^*$-algebras generalize the notion of compact (*locally* compact, if the algebra is possibly non unital) Hausdorff topological space.

Given a measure space $(X,\mu)$, the algebra $L^\infty (X,\mu)$ of essentially bounded functions on $X$ is a von Neumann algebra which completely describes the "measure theory" on $(X,\mu)$.
In NCG, noncommutative von Neumann algebras are considered, which somehow generalize measure theory to the NC setting.

I learn from [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation) wikipedia entry that a certain "chain rule" holds for the space $\mathrm{BV}(\Omega)$ of bounded variation functions on an open subset $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, making it an algebra, and even a Banach algebra.

I would like to know:

> 1) Which geometric aspect of $\Omega$ -if any- is completely described by $\mathrm{BV}(\Omega)$ ?
>
> 2) Which is -if there is any- the "right" NCG generalization of the $\mathrm{BV}(\Omega)$ algebra?

Comment: I don't know of any work done on $BV(\Omega)$ itself - note that its Gelfand dual is even bigger than the Stone-Cech compactification.  Still, the question reminds me of a related construction called the *Higson compactification*.  The Higson compactification of a proper metric space $X$ is the Gelfand dual of the space of continuous functions on $X$ whose variation vanishes at infinity.  It plays an important role in the descent principle which relates the Novikov conjecture to considerations in geometric group theory and metric geometry, for instance.

Comment: If you're interested, you can learn more in Roe's "Lectures on Coarse geometry" as well as in several papers by Dranishnikov and Ferry.

Comment: This probably doesn't help with your question, but something similar was one of the things I had in mind when I asked this question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/90435/how-should-i-define-absolutely-continuous-functions-on-e-g-n-spheres

Comment: In one direction quantum probabilists do use a noncommutative quadratic variation. But I don't think this is the right kind of noncommutative (in Gelfand-Naimark senseof your question); they consider operator-valued functions, but the domain of the function is still just $\mathbb{R}$.